How can i position my Sub Container just below the image?
I want to set the sub container just below the image
i tried using justify content flex-start
adjusted with every containers and possible fix
but none of them worked
don't know what's wrong here
also any proper guide how to implement any UI in React Native
Any suggestion will be helpful
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Image, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { hp, wp } from './helpers/responsive';

export default function App() {


  return (
    //Screen Container//
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      {/* Image Icon Container */}
      <Image style={styles.startIcon} source={require('./assets/images/icon.png')} />
      {/* Sub Container */}
      <View style={styles.subContainer}>
        {/* Title */}
        <Text style={styles.title}>NutriMe</Text>
        {/* Punch Line */}
        <Text style={styles.punchLine}>
          Every nutri facts of {"\n"}daily fruits
        </Text>
        {/* Button Container */}
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={console.log('ah')}>
          {/* Button Text */}
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Explore Now</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  startIcon: {
    height: hp(80),
    width: wp(80),
    resizeMode: 'contain'
  },

  subContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    gap: 14
  },

  title: {
    fontSize: hp(5),
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#44518d'
  },

  punchLine: {
    fontSize: hp(3),
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    color: '#44518d',
    textAlign: 'center'
  },

  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#44518d',
    width: wp(75),
    paddingVertical: 10,
    borderRadius: 10
  },

  buttonText: {
    fontSize: hp(2),
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'normal'
  }
});

This the sample what i want and what i did
using RNExpo for this project

